# Subclipse CollabNet is displaying a mystery icon decorator

Tags: svn, icons, subclipse

The scenario: I'm merging a series of cherry-picked revisions from an SVN branch into trunk. I'm using the Subclipse CollabNet client to do the merge. Everything works great, except that in addition to the files I picked to merge, my working directory shows a series of changes that SVN thinks have changed but that I haven't chosen to merge.

If I do a diff on the files in question, it tells me there are no differences. If I do a commit, I get the screenshot below, with the mystery icon I haven't been able to find documentation of anywhere.

Screenshot:
[image: mystery decorator with green background and white triangle]

Comment: +1 I encountered this icon on a directory after adding one of its files to `svn:ignore` - until I found this post I didn't realize the instruction to ignore files was itself committed to the repo.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248 has everything anyone needs to know about Subclipse icons.

Answer (score 6):

That icon indicates that there are modifications to versioned SVN properties (which do not appear in the Eclipse diff GUI).  In this case, the modifications are to the svn:mergeinfo property that SVN uses for merge tracking.

See this blog post for explanation:

http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/11/where-did-that-mergeinfo-come-from.html

SVN 1.7 is going to have a behavioral change in merge tracking which removes this unexpected aspect of how merge tracking works.